# html form in Django returns none

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to save this HTML form in my table in the database, but I am getting "None" error. I have been on this for some hour. Please any help will be appreciated
[image]

Please, how do i fix this

The is the HTML *order.html* i created

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="payment-form">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" 
                        name="first_name"
                        value="{{request.user.first_name}}">
                   
                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" 
                    placeholder="1234 Main St" required></textarea>
               
                <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success lg w-100 fw-bold" >
                  Proceed to Payment
                </button>

</form>
```

Here is my views.py

```
def add(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get("action") == "post":
        order_key = request.POST.get("order_key")
        user_id = request.user.id
        baskettotal = basket.get_total_price()
        first_name = request.POST.get("first_name")
        last_name = request.POST.get("last_name")
        address = request.POST.get("address")
        print(first_name, last_name, address)

        order = Order.objects.create(
                    first_name = first_name,
                    address=address,
                    total_paid=baskettotal,
                    
            )
            order_id = order.pk
        response = JsonResponse({"success": "Order created"})
        return response
```

The js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function makePayment(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '{% url "order:add" %}',
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
        action: "post",
      },
      success: function (json) {
        console.log(json.success)
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},
    });

   
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You say you've been trying "for some hours" to fix the problem, but what *exactly* have you tried? We need to know this so that we can avoid suggesting fixes that you've already tried.

Comment: I tried using the model form, but I find it difficult to customize the HTML with the styling

Comment: @R.Uziel I am using a jQuery, so this part of the code ***$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '{% url "order:add" %}',
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
        action: "post",
      },*** is the reason why i am using ***if request.POST.get("action") == "post":***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't have to post extra value **action** to determine post request you just have to use `request.method` it will return you all available method you can check for specific method by adding check like this

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

**note** : allways use capitalized method while adding this check
and I'm not sure where you're calling `makePayment()` function and whatever data you're trying to access in your python script you've to pass it through `ajax{data:{}}` like this

```
 function makePayment(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '{% url "order:add" %}',
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
        order_key : "your order key",
        first_name : $('#first_name').val(),
        last_name : $('#last_name').val(),
        address : $('#address').val()
      },
      success: function (json) {
        console.log(json.success)
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},
    });
   
  }
```

and than access it like this

```
def add(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_key = request.POST.get("order_key")
        #....all other fields
```